# Howto customize DB(or Form) Validator in web2py?

Tags: python, web2py

Here are my 2 tables defintion:

```
db.define_table('question',
    Field('category_id',db.category),
    Field('content'),
    Field('number_of_options','integer'),
    Field('has_options_detail','boolean',default=False)) ## Has or not has detail for each option

db.define_table('options_detail', ## This table only for options that have detail explanation
    Field('question_id',db.question),
    Field('serial'), ## Option ordering 
    Field('detail')) ## Detail explanation of option
```

How can I restrict that: db.options_detail.question_id must belong to questions that have field "has_options_detail == True"

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
db.options_detail.question_id.requires = IS_IN_DB(
    db(db.question.has_options_detail==True), 'question.id')
```

Note, the IS_IN_DB validator can take a DAL Set object as the first argument (see [here](http://web2py.com/book/default/chapter/07#Database-Validators)), which enables you to filter the referenced table based on any criteria.

(You could also specify the above `requires` argument directly in the `Field()` declaration.)